# Prove that $AH<\frac{AB+AC}{2}$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Prove that $AH<\frac{AB+AC}{2}$ in $\triangle ABC$. AH is Height of triangle from A to BC.

I thought it can be done by squaring the sides but I didn't get to any good result.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: I think the word "altitude" to describe line segment $AH$ might be a little more apt than "height".  It looks like a neat problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
$AH<AB$ and $AH<AC$. Then
$$2AH<AB+AC$$
Then $$AH<\frac{AB+AC}2$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It seems I thought it is very complicated but it was so simple that I didn't noticed it.